# SQL query to group by data but with order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table booking in which I have data

```
GUEST_NO    HOTEL_NO    DATE_FROM   DATE_TO     ROOM_NO
1           1           2015-05-07  2015-05-08  103
1           1           2015-05-11  2015-05-12  104
1           1           2015-05-14  2015-05-15  103
1           1           2015-05-17  2015-05-20  101
2           2           2015-05-01  2015-05-02  204
2           2           2015-05-04  2015-05-05  203
2           2           2015-05-17  2015-05-22  202
```

What I want is to get the result as.
1 ) It should show output as Guest_no, Hotel_no, Room_no, and column with count as number of time previous three column combination repeated.

So OutPut should like

```
GUEST_NO    HOTEL_NO        ROOM_NO Count
1                1              103   2
1                1              104   1
1                1              101   1
2                2              204   1
```

etc. But I want result to in ordered way e.g.: The output should be `order by bk.date_to desc`

My query is as below its showing me count but if I use order by its not working

```
select bk.guest_no, bk.hotel_no, bk.room_no,
       count(bk.guest_no+bk.hotel_no+bk.room_no) as noOfTimesRoomBooked
from booking bk 
group by bk.guest_no, bk.hotel_no, bk.room_no, bk.date_to
order by bk.date_to desc
```

So with adding order by result is showing different , because as I added order by date_to column so i have to add this column is group by clause too which will end up in different result as below

```
    GUEST_NO    HOTEL_NO        ROOM_NO Count
    1                1              103   1
    1                1              104   1
    1                1              103   1
    1                1              101   1
    2                2              204   1
```

Which is not the output I want.
I want these four column but with order by desc of date_to column and count as no of repetition of first 3 columns

Comment: You mean you get the correct result (except the order) without the ORDER BY, but when you add ORDER BY you get another result? Or is it just the order that's "not working"? Please show result without and with ORDER BY. Also, you can add bk.date_to to the SELECT list, to make things clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a good way to do this would be grouping by guest_no, hotel_no and room_no, and sorting by the maximum (i.e. most recent) booking date in each group.

```
SELECT
    guest_no,
    hotel_no,
    room_no,
    COUNT(1) AS BookingCount
FROM
    booking
GROUP BY
    guest_no,
    hotel_no,
    room_no
ORDER BY
    MAX(date_to) DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
select
  guest_no,
  hotel_no,
  room_no,
  count(*) as Count
from
  booking
group by
  guest_no,
  hotel_no,
  room_no
order by
  min(date_to) desc
```

Or maybe max() instead of min(). SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e684c/3

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
select t.* from
(
select bk.guest_no, bk.hotel_no, bk.room_no, bk.date_to, 
count(*) as noOfTimesBooked from booking bk
group by bk.guest_no, bk.hotel_no, bk.room_no, bk.date_to
) t
order by t.date_to
```

You will also have to select date_to and then group the result by it.
If you use 'group by' clause, SQL Server doesn't allow you to use 'order by'. So you can make a sub query and use 'order by' in the outer query.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server when you write "If you use 'group by' clause, SQL doesn't allow..."?

Comment: @jarlh Yes. There will be an error if you use both 'group by' and 'order by' in the same query

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM 
(select bk.guest_no,bk.hotel_no,bk.room_no
,count(bk.guest_no+bk.hotel_no+bk.room_no) as noOfTimesRoomBooked,
(SELECT MAX(date_to) FROM booking CK
WHERE CK.guest_no=BK.guest_no AND bk.hotel_no=CK.bk.hotel_no
bk.room_no=CK.ROOM_NO ) AS DATEBOOK
from booking bk 
group by bk.guest_no,bk.hotel_no,bk.room_no,bk.date_to) A
ORDER BY DATEBOOK
```

IT MIGHT HELP YOU